# Should I always specify -sPAPERSIZE=a4 when invoking ps2pdf for paper size other than A4?

Tags: compiling, paper-size

When I compile a document with paper size other than A4 as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[A6paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}
 something
\end{document}
```

using `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` steps, should I use `-sPAPERSIZE=a4` switch when invoking `ps2pdf`?

I don't know why TeXnicCenter setup the output profile for `ps2pdf` with `-sPAPERSIZE=a4` switch by default as follows.

`ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="%bm.pdf" -c save pop -f "%bm.ps"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer based on my experience. I don't know whether or not it is a general truth.

- **Using ps2pdf from Miktex**

  Unless you want the top margin to get cropped, you must use `-sPAPERSIZE=a4` when compiling A4 paper. But for other paper size, you can omit this switch without negative effect.
- **Using ps2pdf from TeX Live**

  This switch is no longer needed for any paper size.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a [KOMA Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) class, you should try the `pagesize` document class option. It allows to specify the output driver for writing information about paper size into the document. The comprehensive manual has the necessary details.

Comment: Yes. Try without that switch and see what happens.

Comment: @xport When you use geometry the paper size is recorded in the ps file (via a \special command sent to the dvi) and used in the ps->pdf conversion.